# Load failed: IO error: Error #2032: Stream Error

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Im getting this error when I am trying to call php.

Load failed: HTTP Status = 0
Load failed: IO error: Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://www.xxxxxxx.com/xxx/Login.php

Please help me sort this out,
Code is as below,

```
function checkLogin (e:Event):void
{           
    var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    var phpFileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.xxxxxxx.com/xxx/Login.php");
    phpFileRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    phpFileRequest.data = phpVars;
    phpLoader = new URLLoader();
    phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;   
    phpLoader.addEventListener ( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleIOError );
    phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete );
    phpLoader.addEventListener ( HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, handleHttpStatus );
    phpLoader.addEventListener ( SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, handleSecurityError);

    phpVars.userName = userName.text;
    phpVars.passwords = passwords.text;

    phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);
}

        function handleHttpStatus ( event:HTTPStatusEvent ):void
        {
            trace ( "Load failed: HTTP Status = " + event.status );
        }
        function handleSecurityError ( event:SecurityErrorEvent ):void
        {
            trace ( "Load failed: Security Error: " + event.text );
        }
        function handleComplete ( event:Event ):Void
        {
            trace ( "The data has successfully loaded" );
        }
        function handleIOError ( event:IOErrorEvent ):void
        {
            trace ( "Load failed: IO error: " + event.text );
        }
```

Comment: Very possibly it could be an error in your PHP. Try to ensure your php file has no errors. As an initial test just do a basic echo back from your Login.php file.

Comment: thanx for reply.... still the same error persists

Answer (score 0):

If the PHP is working properly as you say you've tested, than it's probably a cross-domain issue because you're trying to access a blocked domain.

Add a cross-domain policy file.

More info [here](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Flex_Error__2032__Stream_Error-17265.html)